# Generics Classes in Java

Tags: java, class, generics, types, parameters

Why isn't the following code throwing an error/exception?

```
public class UserGenerics <T>
{
    T obj;
    public UserGenerics(T obj) {
        this.obj = obj;
    }
}

class UserGenericsRunner
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        UserGenerics<Integer> ug1 = new UserGenerics("StringObject");
        UserGenerics ug2 = new UserGenerics(23);      
    }
}
```

During the first object creation, a type parameter is passed as an Integer but the object passed to the constructor is a String object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you are creating an instance of a raw type.

You should change

```
UserGenerics<Integer> ug1 = new UserGenerics("StringObject");
```

to

```
UserGenerics<Integer> ug1 = new UserGenerics<>("StringObject");
```

or

```
UserGenerics<Integer> ug1 = new UserGenerics<String>("StringObject");
```

and the compiler will give a compilation error.